# Stop refresh of main query when refreshing related queries in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a query that gets data from the web and puts it in a table.

From this data I make 50 different queries and save all the 50 queries in 50 tables.

Now when I refresh any of the 50 tables that are derived from the main query it also connects to the web to get the data first.

Is there some way that only when I refresh the main query it connects to the web and for every other queries it gets the data locally that is already stored in the main query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try on the main query properties, **de**select: "`Refresh this connection on Refresh All`"

Comment: I think your sub-queries refers to the main-query. Your source for the sub-queries must be the "Main"-table. So, load the "Main"-table in PQ and use this as source for your 50 sub-queries

Comment: You would need to store main data physically to the workbook (as table). If it is only connection PQ does not store the data.